# Counting and delete numbers

Tags: c#

I have read from one file matching and write to another how much times one number is matched.
How to delete every number and leave just one record for this number. What i mean is now I get:

```
Count of matching numbers in this group: 123
Numbers:
...123 times this number i.e 123 lines.
```

How to delete this number and write like this:

```
Count of matching numbers in this group: 123
Number: the number
```

This is how I doing it right now:

```
        string path = "file1.txt";

        var result = (File.ReadLines(path)).OrderBy(x => x).GroupBy(x => x);

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                string outGrp = String.Format("Count of matching numbers in this group: {0}", item.Count());
                Console.WriteLine(outGrp);
                writer.WriteLine(outGrp, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers:");
                writer.WriteLine("Numbers:", true);

                foreach (var member in item)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(member);
                    writer.WriteLine(member, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it's not clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the one liner

```
foreach (var member in item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member);
    writer.WriteLine(member, true);
    break; //<---- slam on the brake (sp?) D:
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to change

```
foreach (var member in item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(member);
    writer.WriteLine(member, true);
}
```

Into something like this:

```
var number = item.First();

Console.WriteLine(number);
writer.WriteLine(number, true);
```

Comment: Yes, I was sure that I must change this foreach but didn't know how. @Weyland Yutani answer is working. Thank to you also!